# Is there a term for one-and-a-half week?

Tags: word-request

I'm wondering if there is a shortcut term for "one-and-a-half weeks", perhaps a word like "sesquiennial" (one-and-a-half years).

Is there such a word? Sesqui-weekly? It sounds funny and wrong. Are there sesqui- terms for other date ranges?

Comment: Since a week is either 7 calendar days or 5 work days, how do you deal with the fractions?

Comment: What constitutes as a "week and a half"? 10 or 11 days?

Comment: I think the constructed word might be along the lines of _sesquihebdomedarian,_ but no one will ever use it.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can think of is "a week and a half", slightly shorter and more relaxed than "one and...".  Not too many people use the sesqui- forms for anything in ordinary writing or speech.